# even if I import ScrollView its not scrolling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview, menuitem, vertical-scrolling

ScrollView not working

```
export default function MenuItem() {
    return(
        <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

        {foods.map((food, index)=>(
        <View key={index}>
        <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
            <FoodInfo food={food} />
            <FoodImage food={food} />
        </View> 
        </View>
        ))}
    </ScrollView>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post your styles as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Flatlist**! its best option for optimizing and memory leaking.

```js
export default function MenuItem() {
    const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
      return (
         <View key={index}>
            <View style={styles.menuItemStyle}>
                <FoodInfo food={item} />
                <FoodImage food={item} />
            </View> 
         </View>
        )
     }
     
    return(
        <FlatList 
          data={foods} 
          renderItem={renderItem} 
          keyExtractor={(item, i) => String(i)} 
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} />
    );
}
```